# How can I start my pattern in first caractere

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I wan't to do a pattern for find "`[ref:math]`". If "`[ref:math]`" is in first position I can't find it but if have another line before no problem.

My pattern is : `([^\t]\[ref\:(.*?)\])`

I put `[^\t]` because I use tabulation when I wan't to found result in a group.

What I the problem ? How can I explain to the pattern to start in first caracter ?

Thank you for your help.

File where I search and I find nothing

```py
[ref:math]
[master_ref:cc]

[type1]
    [ref:aa]
[\type1]
```

File where I search and I find "ref:math"

```py
[master_ref:cc]
[ref:math]

[type1]
    [ref:aa]
[\type1]
```

Comment: Thanks you very much that is perfect and works perfectly. I did not know this site but it is terrible to learn how to make patterns. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `(?:^|[^\t])` non-capturing group with an alternation between start of string or any char but a tab:

```
(?:^|[^\t])(\[ref:(.*?)])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G5KACm/2).

Another way is to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\t)` that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location there is a tab char:

```
(?<!\t)(\[ref:(.*?)])
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G5KACm/3)